# Share value with Nodejs and Pomelo

Tags: javascript, node.js, pomelo

I'm trying to create `userCount` value and i want to share this value with mupltiple file

users.js

```
var userCount=0;

function increment() {
    userCount++;
}

module.exports.userCount=userCount;
```

a.js

```
var users = require('users');
//connection opened
users.userCount++;
log(users.userCount)  //1
// close connection
```

b.js

```
 var users = require('users');
    //connection opened
    log(users.userCount)  // the value is 0 i want the count to be  1
```

I'm not expert with NodeJs neither with javascript

I'm scary for misunderstanding because i don't see this question in any site

Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120117/sharing-modifying-a-variable-between-multiple-files-node-js

Comment: thanks , but doesn't work